# Json response from post, display each result on a div on the page

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am making a post request to an API and it's returning Json. I need help with parsing out the json payload since its an array. I want to display each iteration of the array(result.payload) and assign it to display in a div on my page.

```
function search() {
    $.ajax({
     url: 'api/search',
        data : JSON.stringify({"text": "school","attributes": ["string"], "Population": 0}),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        type : 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
         console.log(result);
            },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    })
}
```

Here is what's being returned in the result
https://gyazo.com/fe0126af26e376ea4cc1f4ec53cfbad8

Answer (score -1):

you could loop through the array you receive and generate a new div for each entry, and add that to an element on your page, you can do that in many ways, this is one.

```
success: function (result) {
   for(const row of result.payload){
      $("#results").append(`<div>${row.campusName}</div>`);
   }
}
```

that requires that you have a div somewhere on the page with the id of `results`

note way this is not super backwards compatible with older browsers.